# Performing arithmetic operation on string list

Tags: python, string, arithmetic-expressions

I have extracted data from a `csv` file using python. 
The data within the `csv` file looks in the following format:

```
a=(10100*b)+(-1289201*c)+(12312312*d)
```

I wrote the code to extract it from the csv file.

```
ar=[]
ins = open(log,"r")
for line in ins:
        ar.append(line)
ins.close()
```

so, `ar[0]='a=(10100*b)+(-1289201*c)+(12312312*d)'`

Now, I need to subsitute the values of b, c and d with a specific floating point variables.

So,I did the following:

```
map = [ ('b','10'), ('c', '20'), ('d','100') ]
for k, v in map: 
 ar[0] = ar[0].replace(k,v)
```

The problem now is I am unable to do any arithmetic operations on the final result, that is, the output is in the following format.

```
`ar[0]='a=(10100*10)+(-1289201*20)+(12312312*100)'`
```

Is there a way in which I can perform some arithmetic operation on the following list format.
I tried to strip the list, but that did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'a=(10100*10)+(-1289201*20)+(12312312*100)'
>>> index = s.find('=') + 1
>>> eval(s[index:])
```

Comment: I get the error: `list` object is not callable.
is `eval` a list?

Answer (score 0):

the answer above is pretty good. here is another way with 1 line less:

```
>>> s = 'a=(10100*10)+(-1289201*20)+(12312312*100)'
>>> exec s
```

you can check the output:

```
>>> a
1205548180
```

the `exec` statement is used to execute expressions, not only evaluate.